# How can I prevent players from having a specific item in their inventory?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-mods

My brother has a problem with hooking people with fishing rods instead of focusing on survival. I know about the `/clear` command, but command blocks are only active when the chunk they're in is loaded, and I'm afraid that he'll go past that to get a fishing rod and start it up again. Since Minecraft is basically infinite, I can't keep placing command blocks whenever he moves away from one.

Is there a mod, command, etc. that can outright prohibit certain items from players' inventories no matter where they are in Minecraft?

Comment: You do realize he'll probably just find another way to be troublesome right? Oh, and no more mending books for you.

Comment: Plus, you don't need to care about the finite range of command blocks because a) chunks are active as long as one player is there, and b) even if they didn't, he'd just get his fishing rod deleted as soon as he gets back there.

Comment: If he's not focusing on survival what's the problem? Just let him starve a few times.

Comment: @user253751 well for one that takes time, and i'd rather enjoy spending time with him since we're half-siblings and he's not with me that often since he goes to school in another state, where his biological mom lives.

Comment: @EgorHans well it would also depend if i was also where the command chunk was loaded, because otherwise we would both be outside its range

Comment: How is preventing him from doing that going to _actually_ solve any problem?

Comment: @o0'. well hes actually very good at finding resources underground, so we would progress a lot faster and more efficiently if he wasnt so focused on hooking everyone

Comment: "I have an interpersonal problem with a fellow player.  How can I solve it with code?"

Comment: Kick him from the server whenever he does this. Or just ban him. He will get the message or not. Either way you will solve the problem.

Comment: Strikes me that rpg stackexchange also frequently has questions roughly of this nature - where players don't have matching ideas of how best to have fun with the game.  At that other site, the answer is almost always: rules based solutions won't address the underlying problem, which is that you're not "on the same page".

Comment: @DanielSchepler we usually are on the same page, its just that sometimes he does crap like this

Comment: and @Yakk, this isn't just for interpersonal problems or anything. I'm also a server maker, and this is very useful for things like that. Please be nicer.

Comment: @TylerH, we play on legacy (xbox), there's no way to kick him without leaving the game (we usually play on worlds in my account). Also, as i said before, we actually progress in the game faster when he's focused on actually playing the game. We've never actually beat (enderdragon) a full survival world (no cheats) on xbox, and we'd like to try

Comment: @PvParkour YOU (singular) would like to try. There's no "we" there. Or you (plural) would actually try that.

Comment: @o0'. actually _we_, as in my brother and I, _would_ like to try, because it's something that neither of us has done before. If _he_ didn't want to do it, then why is he playing? Now can you just stop, please?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You don't need mods. Spawn chunks are always loaded, put your command block there.

Answer (score 15):

Alternate Method: Use a datapack to run the `/clear` command. This works since datapack functions are always loaded, no matter where you are in the world.  You can just reference a function in the minecraft function tag `tick`, and in the function add

```
clear <selector> <item> <count>
```

This will always clear x item(s), from y player(s), no matter where you are.

Comment: can't you paste this into a command block as well? And then just put that one into the spawn chunk (thx @HolyBlackCat) and have it run every tick with a redstone circle

Comment: thats what the datapack trick is for. Datpacks can "hook" a function in to be run each tick. Thats explained in the article about Java functions: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Function_(Java_Edition). Putting them into the Tick tag runs them every tick

Comment: @Hobbamok you could just do that, but from what I understand, the more commands you run every tick, the better it is to use functions instead of command blocks.

Comment: I would accept this as an answer but i cant because for some reason my minecraft hates datapacks and its very hard for me to create them properly. its a good answer, though. thanks!

Comment: @PvParkour what happens when you use a datapack?  Basic datapacks are also easy to learn.  You can find many tutorials online about datapacks.

Comment: my minecraft never loads them properly. sometimes nothing happens and the datapack basically doesnt exist, and other times it crashes my game. it's fine, though, i dont really use datapacks much